# QField - Can't access local storage on iPhone

Tags: qfield, ios, data-storage

I usually use Android products with QField but right now I need to evaluate all portable solutions, which includes iOS. However, just when I come to the data storage access in order to load a new project, I hit a wall. I have been able to successfully load projects from QFieldCloud, but I can't seem to be able to add anything else, unless it has been previously loaded in the specific QField folder (created when the app is installed) or the already selected "favorite folders". Am I missing something here?

I have browsed on QField Ecosystem Documentation website in order to find an answer (https://docs.qfield.org/get-started/storage/), but there is only info for Android OS. Because I don't find it very user-friendly if there are no ways to access other storage solutions (OneDrive, GoogleDrive, DropBox) or even just another local storage folder on my device.

EDITED - December 19th 2022

In French we say,  1 image makes up for a 1000 words. Since no one has commented or tried to answer, I hope this example will make my question clearer.
[image: on left iOS data access page, on right Android data access page]

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424937/qfield-on-ios-import-data/447997#447997